# php array of UK towns/cities

Tags: php

I need a list of towns/cities to be selected in a dropdown menu. I have found this website:

[Link](http://world-gazetteer.com/wg.php?x=&men=gcis&lng=en&des=wg&geo=-4&srt=npan&col=abcdefghinoq&msz=1500&pt=c&va=&geo=-81)

But I require it in a php array, so that I can just loop through it to populate the dropdown. I have searched but cannot find one written in an array, and this one only exports for google earth.

Anyone got a script which does this?

Thanks

Comment: Make the array yourself?

Comment: Why the down votes with no explanations?

Comment: By the way, advanced UK geographical data can be downloaded here: http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/

Comment: I don't see why this is a down vote..I simply wanted to know if there was an easier way. I don't know about you but I dont facny copying and pasting 200 words.

Comment: @Elliott, not sure why you're being downvoted, but there are definitely some viable options provided to you here.

Comment: @Elliott try copy+pasting the table into Excel or OpenOffice's Spreadsheet application. You should be able to remove all the other columns there. This should be possible to in a few minutes even with copy+paste

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered pulling the data from a database instead to populate the drop down.

http://www.sqldumpster.com/databases/geographic/

Building on this you could push this data into a file and read it like another comment has mentioned... or even manipulate this data into a php style array so you can use it as you intented.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was looking for originally but am having trouble inserting that into MS Access db (not my choice of database).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any scripts offhand, but it wouldn't be too difficult to write one that just screen scrapes the data.

Answer (score 2):

It's very unlikely you will find this in ready-made PHP array form.

Consider simply copy+pasting such a list from your brower into a text file, and opening it in PHP using [`file()`](http://php.net/file).

Answer (score 0):

If you download the file, it will save as .php, rename it to file.xml

```
    <?php
if (file_exists('file.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
    foreach ($xml->Document->Placemark as $item){
        $array[] = $item->name;
    }
} else {
    exit('Failed to open file.xml.');
}

print_r($array);
?>
```

That will create an array with the handle $array and assign all the Placemark names to the array values. You can easily loop or edit as needed. I have tested this code and it works.